# Preventing user access to folders outside of the download folder in Nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, configuration, web-config

i have this root folder and nginx websever

```
root /
     /index.html
     /css
         /files...
         /.....
         /.....
     /assets 
     
     /unknown folder name/mods/
                         /client/
                                /download/
                                /scripts/
                                /otherdata/
                         /database/
                  
     /unknown folder name/mods/
                         /client/
                                /download/
                                /scripts/
                                /otherdata/
                         /database/
                  
     /unknown folder name/mods
                         /client/
                                /download/
                                /scripts/
                                /otherdata/
                         /database/
```

what i want is configuration that can do the folowing :

**1. the user can download anything from "download" folder without problems when i give him the correct "unknown folder name" for example this link :**

```
https: // www. mysite .com/aaaabbbb/client/download/scripts/script.lua

aaaabbbb is the unknown folder name.
```

**2. prevent user from accessing other folders if it is not inside "download" folder.**

**3. the user can see index.html**

what i tried is this :

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            location ~/./client/download
            { 
                allow all;
                autoindex on;
            }
        location ~/./ {
            deny all;
                return 404;
        }
    }
```

i want to know is it correct or can someone access my other data , if so , what i can do.
thanks